# Equivalence of definitions for closed set.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I was given definition number $1$ and it'd extremely useful to me if I could prove the equivalence of the following two:

> 1. A set $K$ is closed if and only if its complement is open.
> 2. A set $K$ is closed if every convergent sequence $(x_n)\subseteq K$ converges to $x\in K$.

A set is $A$ is open if every $p\in A$ has a neighborhood $N_r(p)\subseteq A$.

I don't know for sure if these two are equivalent, but I do think so.

Could someone help me out?

Comment: So, this is in a metric space, yes? In a more general setting, 1. implies 2. but not conversely.

Comment: @BrianO Yes. I'm mostly  interested in $(\Bbb R, |x-y|)$, does it work there? I don't see how $2$ does not imply $1$.

Comment: Yes it definitely works there! It fails in spaces where convergence of (countably infinite) *sequences* isn't sufficient to capture convergence, limit points, continuity, etc. In general you need *nets*. Sequences might not be long enough, for example -- example: the long line, with endpoint. But all is well here.

Comment: The key here is to understand that if $x_n\to x\in U$ for some open set $U$, then all except finitely many of the elements of the sequence $x_n$ lie in $U$. You can think of this as an "extension" of the usual epsilon-N definition of convergence. That gets you 1->2, anyway.

Comment: If $K$ is not closed, then there is a point not in $K$ whose every neighborhood intersects $K$. Use this to build a sequence of elements of $K$ to converges to this point not in $K$.

Comment: Def 1 is easier to learn but 2 is much, much, more powerful and once you get used to it (which is hard, i admit) is more useful.  They are equivalent and proving so should be one of the very first theorems after definitions you encounter.  I'm inclined to ask... what does your text say.  It *should* be a basic and prominent theorem.

Comment: @fleablood it's not from any text: definition 1 was given to me in a real analysis course, and while doing some exercises, I thought of definition 2, as using that would trivialize a few of the exercises. I managed to prove the equivalence for a while and failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $K$ is closed according to definition 1. So we know $X \setminus K$ is open (I call the whole space $X$, for definiteness). So for every $x \notin K$ we have an $r > 0$ such that $N_r(x) \subseteq X \setminus K$, or equivalently, $N_r(x) \cap K = \emptyset$.

Now suppose we have a sequence $(x_n)$ where all $x_n \in K$, and this sequence converges to $x$. If $x \notin K$, use the $r > 0$ from above to see that a tail of the sequence lies in $N_r(x)$, and so does *not* lie in $K$. Contradiction, so $x \in K$.

Now suppose $K$ is closed according to definition 2. So we have to show, for $x \notin K$, an $r >0 $ as above (to see $X \setminus K$ is open etc.). Suppose no such $r$ exists, then for every $n$, $r = \frac{1}{n} > 0$ cannot work, so $N_r(x)$ intersects $K$; pick $x_n \in N_{\frac{1}{n}}(x) \cap K$. But then we can show (do this!) that $x_n \rightarrow x$, and $x \notin K$, while all $x_n \in K$, so this contradicts definition 2. So such an $r>0$ does exist.

Comment: 'So for every x∉K we have an r>0 such that Nr(p)⊆X∖K, or equivalently, Nr(p)∩K=∅. ' Did you mean 'Nr(x)' instead of 'Nr(p)'?

Comment: @AaronHill yes, I switched letters. I edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Prove that if a set contains all of limit points (closed) then the complement is open (for each point in complement, there exists a Nbhd that is contained entirely in the complement).